# JavaScript event not responding to clicks

Tags: javascript

```js
const count = document.querySelector("#count")
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("#btn")
let value = 0

btns.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        const styles = e.currentTarget.classList

        if(styles.contains("increase")){
            value++
        } else if(styles.contains("decrease")){
            value--
        } else {
            value = 0
        }

        if(count > 0){
            count.styles.color = "green"
        } 
        if(count < 0){
            count.styles.color = "red"
        }
        if(count === 0){
            count.styles.color = "black"
        }
        count.textContent = value
    })
})
// here I am trying to get button clicks but nothing is happening, not even console logs popup
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <p id="value">0</p>
        <button id="btn decrease">Decrease</button>
        <button id="btn reset">Reset</button>
        <button id="btn increase">Increase</button>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The event is not working, perhaps I forgot to add something?

Comment: I didn't try but your first huge mistake is you use ids in buttons. Switch id= to class=
Maybe then it will work... I didn't check...

Comment: A [id=""](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) is suppose to be a uniq name without spaces, you want to use [class=""](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: made couple of changes

You have `document.querySelector("#count")` but in  html you are using id="value".

As @Ivar pointed out ids should be unique so its better to use class for this case. So changed everything to class. And your if is checking on `count` which is html element and not on the `value`, thats why the count coloring was not working.

```js
const count = document.querySelector("#count")
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
let value = 0

btns.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        const styles = e.currentTarget.classList

        if(styles.contains("increase")){
            value++
        } else if(styles.contains("decrease")){
            value--
        } else {
            value = 0
        }

        if(value > 0){ // changed
            count.style.color = "green"
        } 
        if(value < 0){ // changed
            count.style.color = "red"
        }
        if(value === 0){ // changed
            count.style.color = "black"
        }
        count.textContent = value
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Counter</h1>
        <p id="count">0</p><!--changed-->
        <button class="btn decrease">Decrease</button><!--changed-->
        <button class="btn reset">Reset</button><!--changed-->
        <button class="btn increase">Increase</button><!--changed-->
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't see that. The code worked and I didn't really see that. Let me correct it.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few issues in your script:

- I replaced `id="btn decrease"` with `class="btn decrease"` as the `element.classList` clearly only works on the class attribute.
- your condition `if (count > 0)...` should be `if (value > 0) ...`
- there is no element-attribute `styles`, use `style` instead.

```js
const count = document.querySelector("#value");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
let value = 0

btns.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        const styles = e.currentTarget.classList

        if(styles.contains("increase")){
            value++
        } else if(styles.contains("decrease")){
            value--
        } else {
            value = 0
        }

        if(value > 0){
            count.style.color = "green"
        } else if(value < 0){
            count.style.color = "red"
        } else {
            count.style.color = "black"
        }
        count.textContent = value
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Counter</h1>
  <p id="value">0</p>
  <button class="btn decrease">Decrease</button>
  <button class="btn reset">Reset</button>
  <button class="btn increase">Increase</button>
</div>
```

The whole script could be shortened quite a bit by avoiding repetitions:

```js
const count = document.querySelector("#value");
document.querySelectorAll(".container button").forEach(function(btn,i){
 btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
   let val=+count.textContent;
   val = i===1 ? 0 : val+(i?+1:-1)
   count.textContent = val
   count.style.color = val>0?"green":val<0?"red":"black";
 });
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Counter</h1>
  <p id="value">0</p>
  <button>Decrease</button>
  <button>Reset</button>
  <button>Increase</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternate solution is quite nice. Didn't know about `=+ `!

Comment: `=+` is actually just a juxtaposition of two operators: the assignment operator `=`  and the unary sign-operator `+` . They act independently from one another. `+` takes care of the implicit type conversion to `Number`.